# Perl debugger: Trace variable in stacktrace

Tags: perl, debugging, printstacktrace

With the builtin Perl debugger I am able to print a stack trace. However, I am only interested in a certain variable not a full stack trace of 30k+ lines.
Is it possible to only display executed lines that contain a specified variable?

**Example**

Suppose I would like to trace the variable $data. Then I only want to want to see line 4,7,8,10 not the others.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $data = 1;
my $otherdata = "Diamond";

$data += 1;
my $rename = $data;

if($rename =~ /2/){

    print "hello world";

}
```

**Stack trace**

```
perl -d:Trace script.pl

script.pl:4: my $data = 1;
script.pl:5: my $otherdata = "Diamond";
script.pl:7: $data += 1;
script.pl:8: my $rename = $data;
script.pl:10: if($rename =~ /2/){
script.pl:12:        print "hello world";
```

Comment: I think you just mean "trace" and not "stack trace".

Comment: I'm not aware of a built-in way to do what you're asking, but you can use watch expressions to pause the debugger when the value of a variable changes. I think this would be more useful than seeing every single line that references a variable, whether the value changes or not.

Answer (score 0):

I found a **partially** working solution by using [Variable::Magic](http://search.cpan.org/~vpit/Variable-Magic-0.59/lib/Variable/Magic.pm). The variable tracer (see code below) $wiz is attached to the variable $data. Whenever $data is accessed, it will call the "get" method and execute sub {print "875ABC8768"}.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Variable::Magic qw<wizard cast VMG_OP_INFO_NAME>;

my $data = 1;

{ # A variable tracer
my $wiz = wizard(
get  => sub { print "875ABC8768"},
 );

 cast $data, $wiz;
}

my $otherdata = "Diamond";

$data += 1;
my $rename = $data;

if($rename =~ /2/){

   print "hello world";

}
```

By using the following steps, I was able to extract the executed lines that contain the variable $data:

1) Write a Stack trace to a file:

```
perl -d:Trace script.pl 2> stacktrace.txt
```

2) Extract the lines with variable $data:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

open(FILE,"<","stacktrace.txt");
my $previous = <FILE>;

     while (my $current = <FILE>) {

        if($current =~ /875ABC8768/){
            print $previous;
        }

        $previous = $current;
     }

close(FILE);
```

Execute script:

```
perl extractor.pl

>> magic.pl:17: $data += 1;
>> magic.pl:18: my $rename = $data;
```

Answer (score -1):

You could just append (to the trace command) this semi-automated way of filtering on only the line numbers that contain the variable:

```
|egrep ":($(echo $(grep -n '$data\b' script.pl|cut -d: -f1)|tr ' ' '|')):"
```

Comment: This approach won't follow references. Say `$foo` is a reference to `$bar`: `$foo = \$bar;`. If you only grep for `$bar`, the line `$$foo = "foo";` will be filtered out, even though it changes the value of `$bar`.

Comment: I agree with ThisSuitIsBlackNot, as references to the variable will not be caught.

Comment: Have a look at Variable::Magic http://search.cpan.org/~vpit/Variable-Magic-0.59/lib/Variable/Magic.pm You could add a hook that prints out the variable's value whenever it is accessed.

Comment: Thank you xxfelixxx, by using Variable::Magic I am able to add a variable tracer that gets called each time the variable is accessed.

Comment: @user2134762 Can you add that as an answer and show your implementation? It could be helpful to future visitors who have the same question.